# clickoutside directive preventing other click events to fire in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have implemented click outside directive for closing side bar. Directive is working fine but the content of side bar ( any click event is not firing). How to stop propagting that event?

**Here is my clickoutside.js**

````
    import Vue from 'vue';

const nodeList = [];
const ctx = '@@clickoutsideContext';

let startClick;
const counter = 0;

const isServer = Vue.prototype.$isServer;

/**
 * added this on event function for direct dom manipulation
 */
const onEvent = (function() {
    if (!isServer && document.addEventListener) {
        return function(element, event, handler) {
            if (element && event && handler) {
                element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
            }
        };
    }
    return function(element, event, handler) {
        if (element && event && handler) {
            element.attachEvent(`on${event}`, handler);
        }
    };
})();

!isServer &&
    onEvent(document, 'mousedown', e => {
        startClick = e;
    });

!isServer &&
    onEvent(document, 'mouseup', e => {
        nodeList.forEach(node => node[ctx].documentHandler(e, startClick));
    });

// setting up mouse events

function createDocumentHandler(el, binding, vnode) {
    return function(mouseup = {}, mousedown = {}) {
        if (
            !vnode ||
            !vnode.context ||
            !mouseup.target ||
            !mousedown.target ||
            el.contains(mouseup.target) ||
            el.contains(mousedown.target) ||
            el === mouseup.target ||
            (vnode.context.popperElm &&
                (vnode.context.popperElm.contains(mouseup.target) ||
                    vnode.context.popperElm.contains(mousedown.target)))
        )
            return;

        if (
            binding.expression &&
            el[ctx].methodName &&
            vnode.context[el[ctx].methodName]
        ) {
            vnode.context[el[ctx].methodName]();
        } else {
            el[ctx].bindingFn && el[ctx].bindingFn();
        }
    };
}

/**
 * v-clickoutside
 * @desc Only trigger when click outside
 * @example
 * ```vue
 * <div v-element-clickoutside="handleClose">
 * ```
 */
export default {
    bind(el, binding, vnode) {
        nodeList.push(el);
        const id = counter + 1;
        el[ctx] = {
            id,
            documentHandler: createDocumentHandler(el, binding, vnode),
            methodName: binding.expression,
            bindingFn: binding.value
        };
    },

    update(el, binding, vnode) {
        el[ctx].documentHandler = createDocumentHandler(el, binding, vnode);
        el[ctx].methodName = binding.expression;
        el[ctx].bindingFn = binding.value;
    },

    unbind(el) {
        const len = nodeList.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
            if (nodeList[i][ctx].id === el[ctx].id) {
                nodeList.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        delete el[ctx];
    }
};
````

**This is where i am adding the directive in component template**

```
<v-main :style="{ paddingTop: '48px' }" >
      <div v-clickoutside = "closeEvent">
        <v-container fluid class="pa-0">
            <keep-alive>
                <router-view name="layout" />
            </keep-alive>
            <router-view />
        </v-container>
      </div>
        <keep-alive>
               <SideBar v-model="drawer" />
        </keep-alive>
    </v-main>
```

In this Side bar is having multiple buttons but onclick is not working and side bar closes while clicking those buttons.

Answer (score 1):

the @mousedown runs before the @click event and that is why you are unable to click on the contents of your sidebar. I suggest looking into event modifiers (.stop in particular) from the official docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html or figuring the appropriate event to fire.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But how can i handle it in my current code before event listeners.